# Way to detect "Refused to display document because display forbidden by X-Frame-Options." error?

Tags: javascript, frame, x-frame-options

I am using 'google viewer' to view some documents.
Only problem is, if the browser has a google-login that is in "limbo" it shows nothing and the "Refused to display document because display forbidden by X-Frame-Options." error occurs and is shown in the console.

What I mean by "limbo" is when a login is known but the user has to re-enter their password to reverify themselves.

Is there a method to detect when this error occurs so I can display a popup error to notify the user?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9534001/want-to-call-a-function-if-iframe-doesnt-load-or-loads

Answer (score 2):

Had a same problem and the only solution found was to check if `iframe` finished loading after some time:

```
$(function () {
    $('#DtLoadingIframe').on('load', (function () {
        clearTimeout(errloading);
    }));

    var errloading = setTimeout(function () {
        window.location = "App.aspx";
    }, 5000);
});
```

So actually, users that approved my app, are now "automatically" signed in within `iframe`.

Others are redirected after 5 seconds (for those 5 seconds I have some small text explaining the situation).

Perhaps it could be done better by using this approach?

http://static.jtwb.dotcloud.com/test-cases/html/content-disposition-attachment.html