# Facebook App Error forbidden by X-Frame-Options

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I am building a facebook app currently it is in sandbox mode. My code :-

index.php

```
<?php
ob_start();
@session_start();

require 'facebook.php';
include_once('config.php');


$facebook = new Facebook(array(
            'appId' => APP_ID,
            'secret' => SECRET_KEY,
            ));

$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }


    if (!empty($user_profile )) {
        # User info ok? Let's print it (Here we will be adding the login and registering routines)

        $username = $user_profile['name'];

        //echo '->'.$username;exit;
        $uid = $user_profile['id'];
        $email = $user_profile['email'];


        @session_start();
        //$_SESSION['id'] = $userdata['id'];
        $_SESSION['oauth_id'] = $uid;

        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
        $_SESSION['oauth_provider'] = 'facebook';
        header("Location: home.php");

        ?>

        <?php


    } else {
        # For testing purposes, if there was an error, let's kill the script
        die("There was an error.");
    }
} else {
    # There's no active session, let's generate one
    $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array( 'scope' => 'email'));
    header("Location: " . $login_url);
}
?>
```

Here I am checking if the user is login or not if it is a logged in user then redirect to home,php else to login page of facebook.

but when i run my app on facebook it throws error on console :-

> Refused to display document because display forbidden by X-Frame-Options because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'

[image]

Also I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9491540/refused-to-display-document-because-display-forbidden-by-x-frame-options) solution but it wont work

Comment: It's better to copy & paste the error in the question instead of posting screenshot. I'm too old to read small texts.

Comment: @ShivanRaptor I also paste the error in my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not display the login dialog within any kind of frames – that’s an anti-phishing measure, the user is supposed to be always able to verify that the login dialog they are shown is indeed from facebook.com, and not a fake loaded from any other site.

You have to redirect to it in the top window instance. This can not be done server-side, so you have to use JavaScript:

```
<script>top.location.href = "…";</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply i tried this <script>top.location.href="apps.facebook.com/myapp/home.php"</script>; but it shows the same error

Comment: _As I said,_ you have to call _the login dialog_ in the top frame … and that’s not the address of the login dialog. `header("Location: " . $login_url)` in your code is what you have to replace with JavaScript.

Comment: OMG !! it worked. I was redirecting home.php using js but as you said now i used  <script> window.top.location = '<?php echo $login_url;?>'; </script> which worked :) thanks bro

Comment: can you help on this what should i add to $facebook->getLoginUrl(array( 'scope' => 'email')); so that it also ask user to photo permission

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/extended-profile-properties/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of header redirect use JS redirect as

```
<script>top.location.href="THE URL"</script>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, you mean to say should i do like this top.location.href="home.php" ??

Comment: I changed the url to :- <script>top.location.href="https://apps.facebook.com/myapp/home.php"</script> but it throws the same error

Comment: Hmm how about <script>
window.top.location = 'apps.facebook.com/myapp/home.php';
</script>

Comment: Can u add the following on the top of your home.php header('X-Frame-Options: GOFORIT');

Comment: same result....from my account i have build this app and i added my friend as developer. When i open this app through my id it open and on console it shows error -GOFORIT' is not a recognized directive. The header will be ignored. AND when I try to open this app through my friend id it shows error - Refused to display document because display forbidden by X-Frame-Options because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'

Comment: hmm this is weird since I had similar issue and got resolved by JS re-direct.