# Want to call a function if iframe doesn't load or load's?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, onload

I have a `iframe` in my page. If the `iframe` doesn't load, want it to `alert` the message "**pdf not found**" and if the `iframe` does load, it should `alert` "**pdf opened**".

Does anyone know how to achieve that?

Comment: Are you loading a PDF file into the iframe?

Comment: @ŠimeVidas yes . i want like this if pdf cannot get loaded from server a message box "alert " should come

Comment: Is the PDF on the same domain as the web-page?

Comment: How do you make Ajax calls? Which library do you use?

Comment: No i haven't use any ajax calls for this part? Mootools am using

Comment: The idea is to first make an Ajax request in order to figure out if the response is indeed a PDF document. With Ajax, you have access to the response-information, so you can figure out if it's a "200 OK" response containing a PDF document (in which case you have to manually load the PDF into the iframe), or a "404 Not Found" response, etc.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas for frame onreadystate can be used but it only tells that whether the frame is created or not.. It doesn't tells about the pdf document loaded.. the stage of frame creation is , interactive,loading,created

Comment: Well, that's why I suggested making an Ajax request first. Ajax requests provide response information, that iframes don't provide.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So, the idea is to use an Ajax-request to "test" the URL. Ajax-requests enable you to bind "success" and "error" handlers - unlike `<iframe>` elements which only provide a "load" handler.

Of course, Ajax-requests are restricted by the Same Origin Policy (unless the web-server enables CORS), but you stated that the PDF is on the same domain, so there shouldn't be any issues.

Also, you stated that you use the Mootools library - I use jQuery, so I can only provide you with a jQuery solution, but since we're making a simple Ajax-request with "success" and "error" handlers, you should be able to recreate a Mootools solution based on my jQuery solution easily.

So, given an iframe and an URL:

```
var iframe = $( '#iframe' )[0]; // reference to IFRAME element
var url = 'files/document1.pdf';
```

The Ajax-request:

```
$.get( url, function () {
    iframe.onload = function () { alert( 'PDF opened!' ); };
    iframe.src = url;
}).error( function () { alert( 'PDF not found' ); });
```

**Success-demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/CZWdL/1/show/
**Error-demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/CZWdL/2/show/

So, if the Ajax-request triggers an "error" event, we simply alert the "Not found" message immediately. If, however, the Ajax-request triggers a "success" event, we assign a "load" handler to our IFRAME element (this "load" handler will eventually alert the "Loaded" message), and set the URL to its `src` property manually.

Comment: This one won't work either. The JQuery error callback detects the status code. There are cases the server returns status 200 together with x-frame-options:SAMEORIGIN. google.com does this.

Comment: I mean it won't work generally. But for the OP's case, i.e. to load pdf in iframe, it should work.

Comment: Wait, both JQuery and the iFrame are fetching the URL? Isn't that a little heavy?

Comment: @AdamAugusta Yes. Now that you've mentioned it, the first request does not need to be a GET request. A HEAD request will get the job done too. So, one can do a HEAD to see if the URL exists like so: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/333634/http-head-request-in-javascript-ajax or so http://stackoverflow.com/a/4715334/425275

Answer (score -3):

You can simply add this code in your iframe when it's loaded :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!-- 
        window.top.window.callback();
//-->
</script>
```

And in your top page :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
        function callback() {
                alert("File loaded!");
        }
//-->
</script>
```

If your callback function is not called after 30 seconds, you can say that your pdf is not loaded.

---

Edit :
Your first file (with the iframe) :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        <!--
            function callback() {
                alert("This file doesn't exist");
            }
        //-->
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe src="load_pdf.php?f=test.pdf" style="width:900px;height:500px;"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

The second (php file) :

```
<?php
$file = $_GET['f'];

if(is_file($file)) {
    header('Content-type: application/pdf');
    readfile($file);
}
else {
    // This file doesn't exist
    echo '
        <script type="text/javascript">
        <!-- 
                window.top.window.callback();
        //-->
        </script>
    ';
}
?>
```

Don't forget to secure the $_GET['f']

Comment: Can you please upload some example in fiddle

Comment: I don't think this solution will work for this particular scenario as the page inside the iframe isn't HTML, it is a PDF document.